# Magento 2.4.4 - Some orders are stuck on the 'Pending' status and not changing to 'Processing

Tags: order-status

For my Magento 2.4.4 page, normally when payment is collected from Stripe, order status will move automatically from 'Pending' to 'Processing'. For most orders, this works perfectly. However, there are a few orders (1 in 15 orders) that the status will be stuck in 'Pending', and not change to 'Processing' despite the status log showing that it is 'Processing', plus Stripe confirming that the payment is Successful.

This is an issue for my page as the status showing as 'Processing' is needed for things such as 3PL integration (order shipment created on 3PL platform, reward points credited to customer account, Gift Card code (if a gift card was purchased) creation and sent to customer, etc).

Has anyone come across a similar situation, or know how to fix this?

[image: Order is 'Processing' but status is reflecting as 'Pending']

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I've got the same issue

Comment: Nope, still stuck with this issue and have no idea why it happens or how to fix. My manual solution is to go into the sales orders SQL table and change new/pending to processing.

Comment: I did almost the same: I ended up creating a btn in the top bar of the page to save the right state so the order can go on, just a temporary solution until stripe fixes this bug

Answer (score 0):

Did you find solution for this issue? I've got the same issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/206182)